# Delete some part of the string in beginning and some at last in java

Tags: java

I want a dynamic code which will trim of some part of the String at the beginning and some part at last. I am able to trim the last part but not able to trim the initial part of the String to a specific point completely. Only the first character is deleted in the output.

```
public static String removeTextAndLastBracketFromString(String string) {
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(string);
  int i=0;
  do {
    str.deleteCharAt(i);
    i++;
  } while(string.equals("("));
  str.deleteCharAt(string.length() - 2);
  return str.toString();
}
```

This is my code. When I pass `Awaiting Research(5056)` as an argument, the output given is `waiting Research(5056`. I want to trim the initial part of such string till ( and I want only the digits as my output. My expected output here is - `5056`. Please help.

Comment: Your do-while-loop is using the unmodified input parameter for its check, while in reality you probably want to check the char at the current i position. But you might want to look into regular expressions for an easier way to extract the desired text from the input.

Comment: Do you want to extract only numbers, regardless of where they are located, or do you want to extract whatever is enclosed in brackets - `(extraction target)`.

Comment: Well to answer what happened, "string.equals("(")" is equal to "Awaiting Research(5056)".equals("("); which is false and hence it run once. If you figure to use while(string.charAt(i)); you'll notice that i runs into a length issue due to direct mutation of variable. You might need more debugging to solve this programmatically if you want to try out to understand more, but it'll be fun. If possible get some tools that can do "DEBUG", and you can understand your code line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need loops (in your code), you can use `String.substring(int, int)` in combination with `String.indexOf(char)`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String input = "Awaiting Research(5056)";
    // find the braces and use their indexes to get the content
    String output = input.substring(
                        input.indexOf('(') + 1, // index is exclusive, so add 1
                        input.indexOf(')')
                    );
    // print the result
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
5056
```

### Hint:

Only use this if you are **sure** the input will always contain a `(` and a `)` with `indexOf('(') < indexOf(')')` or handle `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s, which will occur on most `String`s not matching the braces constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to look one numeric value of the string, try split the string with regex for the respective numeric value and then you'll have the number separated from the string
e.g:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("somestringwithnumberlike123");
 
 if(matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regexp to extract what you need is a better option :

```
String test = "Awaiting Research(5056)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, battery use regular expression to extract your interested part.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\().*(?=\\))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Awaiting Research(5056)");
if(matcher.find())
{
    return matcher.group();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to solve the problem e.g. using the `String.indexOf(..)` and `String.substring(from,to)`. But if, for some reason you want to stick to your approach, here are some hints:

Your code does what is does because:

- `string.equals("(")` is only true if the given string is exacly "("
- the `do {code} while (condition)`-loop executes code once if condition is not true -> think about using the `while (condition) {code}` loop instead
- if you change the condition to check for the character at i, your code would remove the first, third, fifth and so on: After first execution i is 1 and char at i is now the third char of the original string (because the first has been removed already) -> think about always checking and removing charAt 0.